# vba find value then paste another into different cell in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently running a Macro that looks for a value from column A of 'sheet 1' in column C of sheet 2, if these match then the value from column B of sheet 1 should be copied to column M of the corresponding row in sheet 2.

The Macro I have works, but because this is a massive worksheet, the loop in it is taking far too much time. This is because sheet 1 has around 300,000 rows and the value in each instance is unique. in Sheet 2 there are around 50,000 rows. It's been running overnight and has only reached 60,000 rows in sheet 1 so far

I'm by no means a VBA expert, or even intermediate but from what I've read maybe using Find would be faster than looking for a match and looping?

this is the macro i'm currently using

```
 Option Explicit

Sub lookupandcopy()
Application.Screenupdating = True

Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim sh_1, sh_3 As Worksheet
Dim MyName As String

Set sh_1 = Sheets("sheet1") 
Set sh_3 = Sheets("sheet2")


lastRow1 = sh_1.UsedRange.Rows.Count 

For j = 2 To lastRow1
MyName = sh_1.Cells(j, 1).Value 


lastRow2 = sh_3.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastRow2
    If sh_3.Cells(i, 3).Value = MyName Then
        sh_3.Cells(i, 13).Value = sh_1.Cells(j, 2).Value 
    End If

    Next i

  Next j

Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

If I've missed anything off or any other detail that's needed please let me know!

Comment: Line 3 should be Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Comment: Sorry, it's right in the actual code, but it's running on another machine so I've had to re-type it out here.

Comment: Why is sh_3 is being used to refer to sheet2? A crucial question is if the values in sheet1 column A are unique. If they are -- why not use a simple vlookup?

Comment: sh_3 is used to avoid me mistyping (gorilla like fingers) and would a Vlookup be faster? I've always perceived it to be too slow for massive amounts of data and generally try to avoid it

Comment: @Els but why not sh_2 for "sheet2"?

Comment: it's just because i'm working on a small keyboard and am likely to hit '1' instead of '2'.

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using columns A and B in sheet1 as a dictionary (and accessing the values by a linear search). Why not load the values into a dictionary objects which has O(1) search? Make sure that your project includes a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (tools > references in the VBE if you haven't done such things) then try:

```
Sub lookupandcopy()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim AVals As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim sh_1, sh_3 As Worksheet
    Dim MyName As String

    Set sh_1 = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set sh_3 = Sheets("sheet2")

    With sh_1
        lastRow1 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count 'last row in spreadsheet
        lastRow1 = .Cells(lastRow1, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column A
        'load the AVal dict
        For j = 2 To lastRow1
            MyName = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            If Len(MyName) > 0 Then AVals.Add MyName, .Cells(j, 2).Value
        Next j
    End With

    With sh_3
        lastRow2 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count
        lastRow2 = .Cells(lastRow2, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column 3
        For i = 2 To lastRow2
            MyName = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            If AVals.Exists(MyName) Then
                .Cells(i, 13).Value = AVals.Item(MyName)
            End If
         Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you have repeated values in column A then you would need to do something like store as values collections of row indices where the value occurs, but the effort of setting up such a dictionary would still be better than using nested loops.

Comment: Would having duplicate values in column B cause issues, i'm trying to run your code but it's giving me the following error
'Runtime Error 457'
This key is already associated with an element of this collection'

Comment: So -- you must have duplicates values in column A. I'll try to revise my code later on today to reflect that.

Comment: @ELs your line sh_3.Cells(i, 13).Value = sh_1.Cells(j, 2).Value  confuses me. If the same value myName can occur multiple times in column A then this would set the ultimate value of Cells(i,13) to the value in column B corresponding to the last occurrence of myName in column A. I don't think that you want this -- so I suspect that your values in Column A are distinct *except for blank cells*. If usedrange (in a different part of sheet 1) drops below the part of A that contains the keys then you are trying to process more of column A then you want. I tweaked the code a bit. See if it works now.

Comment: i've added your updated code and it seems to be working great!

Comment: @ELs When data gets to be as large as yours, going from a quadratic to a linear time algorithm can make an enormous difference. My guess is that this runs about 50,000 times faster than what you had before. The dictionary was the main saver, but the two With statements probably helped a bit as well.