# VBA Dictionary to search, match, and paste: Unknown Error

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

Ok, so I pulled this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071004/vba-find-value-then-paste-another-into-different-cell-in-another-column),  and have been trying to adapt it with little success. I may simply be misunderstanding the original or am missing some other fundamental flaw (like perhaps the code was written for an older iteration of excel).

I have a Master Sheet (2018) with a lot of different rows with different tasks assigned to an inspector. Each task has a number in column G that is unique, and an inspector can have more than one task--but no task has more than one inspector. Column G is unique--the numbers do not repeat. Each inspector has his/her own sheet that is updated using a different excel--inspector sheets are formatted exactly as the master sheet is, all columns are the same. The inspector will put in the date, in their own sheet, a task is completed (date goes in Column R) and I'm trying to use this code so that when an inspector completes a task and put in the date, he clicks a button and that date is copied to column R in the master sheet in the correct row that matches the correct task number.

Like so:
[image: copyPaste]

I'm using this code to work around using a formula like index match or vlookup (far too much data and the workbook is designed to be used by individuals who do not know how to drag down a formula when new records are added).

```
Sub dates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim AVals As New Dictionary
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim sh_insp, sh_2018 As Worksheet
Dim MyName As String

Set sh_insp = Activesheet
Set sh_2018 = Sheets("2018")

With sh_insp
    lastRow1 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count 'last row in spreadsheet
    lastRow1 = .Cells(lastRow1, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column G
    'load the AVal dict
    For j = 18 To lastRow1
        MyName = .Cells(j, 7).Value
        If Len(MyName) > 0 Then AVals.Add MyName, .Cells(j, 7).Value
    Next j
End With

With sh_2018
    lastRow2 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count
    lastRow2 = .Cells(lastRow2, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column G
    For i = 18 To lastRow2
        MyName = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        If AVals.Exists(MyName) Then
            .Cells(i, 18).Value = AVals.Item(MyName)
        End If
     Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm getting a 'User-defined type not defined' at the `Dim AVals as New Dictionary`   which prevents me from really even seeing if it works or not. Also, sometimes a task isn't assigned yet and you have tasks assigned but not completed. I don't want it to erase anyone's data only add data when a task number is matched. Does this make sense?

Comment: Using early binding you must set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: The pic is terrific.

Comment: @SJR I put `Dim AVals As Object: Set AVals = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")` and now it's copying column G, where it matches to column R. Trying to fix it and it's giving me Run-time error '457'

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/615472) will help show you how to enable early binding for the scripting runtime.

Comment: @PeterT I was able to figure out the binding issue, it's the execution after that which is presenting a problem now (see my last comment).

Comment: Then just use `Set AVals = New Dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
If Len(MyName) > 0 Then AVals.Add MyName, .Cells(j, 7).Value
```

with this:

```
If Len(MyName) > 0 And Len(.Cells(j, 18)) > 0 Then AVals.Add MyName, .Cells(j, 18).Value
```

Comment: awesome! works sort of! but it doesn't start actually pasting the values in the master sheet until row 36 and I have no idea why. Its not that there aren't tasks assigned to that inspector before row 36 and it's not that those tasks aren't completed. They are, there should be dates being pasted in col. R above row 36----I just don't know why they aren't. Everything's typed and formatted correctly It's like one issue gets solved and another more annoying issue takes it's place. I've been working on this for over a week and I have no idea what I did to anger excel so much.

Comment: It seems that your original question has been answered, if so then accept the answer. As regards your new question, I'm afraid your will have to post it separately and provide more info (i.e. a print shot of both `sh_insp` and `sh_2018` worksheets) so we can then determine what adjustments your code needs.