# VBA Dictionary to Match/Copy/Paste not working

Tags: excel, vba

I was advised to post this as a second question, but it is somewhat of a continuation of my first question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275802/vba-dictionary-to-search-match-and-paste-unknown-error/50276484#50276484).

I have code (a scripting dictionary) that is meant to match up columns and paste a third value in another column in the correct row. Now, the issue I'm having (the new issue) is that the code does not seem to begin pasting from the first row of my inspector sheets to the first full row in my master sheet. Assume each sheet has many many records and that new ones are constantly added (it's why I try not to use restrictive defined ranges).

Like so:

Lavoie has all his WO#s in his own little sheet. He's meant to update the 'Date Inspector Cleared' himself, manually, then hit a button and then that date is copy pasted to column R in the master sheet after being matched via WO# (which is always unique and never repeats) to the WO# in the master sheet (2018). Images below(I had to black out some of the sensitive information--just assume it's not important.)

Lavoie's sheet:
[image: Lavoie]

Master sheet:
[image: Master2018]

Here's my code:

```
Sub dates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim AVals As Object: Set AVals = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim sh_insp, sh_2018 As Worksheet
Dim MyName As String

Set sh_insp = ActiveSheet
Set sh_2018 = Sheets("2018")

With sh_insp
    lastRow1 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count 'last row in spreadsheet
    lastRow1 = .Cells(lastRow1, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column G
    'load the AVal dict
    For j = 18 To lastRow1
        MyName = .Cells(j, 7).Value
        If Len(MyName) > 0 And Len(.Cells(j, 18)) > 0 Then AVals.Add MyName, .Cells(j, 18).Value
    Next j
End With

With sh_2018
    lastRow2 = .Range("A:A").Rows.Count
    lastRow2 = .Cells(lastRow2, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'last used row in column G
    For i = 18 To lastRow2
        MyName = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        If AVals.Exists(MyName) Then
            .Cells(i, 18).Value = AVals.Item(MyName)
        End If
     Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have WO#s that are cleared--why won't the code copy paste those values, why is it skipping?

Comment: You should read [mcve]. Don't know if it's the cause of your problems, but `Set sh_insp = ActiveSheet` is risky as perhaps the wrong sheet is active when the code is run?

Comment: @SJR, I have another macro that runs a userform and restricts access so the correct sheet for the correct person is always displayed :). But I will read that, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data starts at row 2 or 3 and you start adding records to the dictionary and validating the records in `2018` from row 18

Change 18 to the proper row in these lines:

```
For j = 18 To lastRow1
For i = 18 To lastRow2
```